# install "pip undetected-chromedriver" for selenium python

Tags: selenium, pip, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to make an autofiller using selenium, but it couldn't be done. so I decided to use undetected chromedriver to finish the automation.

I am having some difficulty here to import the undetected-chromedriver.

I already downloaded it by inputting the command line: **pip install undetected-chromedriver**

But when I put the **import undetected_chromedriver as uc**, the complier doesn't recognize it.

---

---

*Below is the Error message after trying to import undetected-chromedriver:*

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
```

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'undetected_chromedriver'**

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```sh
# navigate into the project directory with your python script
cd presearch

# create virtual environment
python3 -m venv venv

# activate the virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate

# install required pip packages
pip3 install undetected-chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to check if the undetected_chromedriver package is in the list

```
pip list
or 
pip3 list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple python versions installed, you might check if you actually installed it in the right one.